# How to select variables for a regression?

Tags: r, regression

This is my first time working with data outside of what's been provided in class. I'm having trouble deciding how to go about this and I'd really appreciate any feedback from those who have done this much longer than I!

I have a data set containing all mass shootings and gun laws in the US with 142 variables. It essentially consists of state, year, number of mass shootings per 100k people, 137 binary variables for state laws, and a few other variables.

I want to determine three things: 1) does having more gun laws increase mass shootings? 2) does living near a state with few gun laws increase mass shootings in states with more gun laws (think California and Texas)? 3) what laws have the strongest impact on mass shootings?

**QUESTIONS**

1. I think I should use the top states with the most gun laws and the bottom states with the least gun laws, but I'm not sure what percentage of each to use. Should I use an arbitrary number like the top 10% of states and the bottom 10% of states?
2. What would be the most efficient way to identify states with many laws that border states with few laws? Is there a way to do this in R? Or would this need to be done manually by looking at a state map?
3. There are a lot of gun laws. How should I select which laws to include in the regression?
4. I currently have two similar explanatory variables: 1. total_laws (total number of laws a state has) and 2. percentage_of_laws_used (laws a state has/total possible laws*100). Should I exclude one of these variables from the regression?

I appreciate any insight you all can provide!

Comment: It is worth remembering that correlation does not demonstrate causation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asked a lot of questions so here are my answers. I'm not an expert on statistics so these are just my intuitions:

**1) I think I should use the top states with the most gun laws and the bottom states with the least gun laws, but I'm not sure what percentage of each to use. Should I use an arbitrary number like the top 10% of states and the bottom 10% of states?**

Why not use the entire range of states? This would give you both a more realistic approximation of the relationship between laws and gun sales, and then after you run the regression you can always explain why the results ended up the way they did. In principle you could divide up the data in this way and possibly assign them categories, but I think it would be more valuable to not do this (in my opinion). Consider for example [this recent question where I ran a log-log regression on population and robbery incidence.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/593269/how-to-interpret-the-intercept-of-this-log-log-regression) If I had just used New York and California as "big states" and New Hampshire and Rhode Island as "small" states, I wouldn't really know the entire bandwidth of the relationship of population and robberies. Consider for example if there is some non-linear relationship in your regression because of "average gun law" states. If you exclude them you may lose a very important insight in your data.

**2) What would be the most efficient way to identify states with many laws that border states with few laws? Is there a way to do this in R? Or would this need to be done manually by looking at a state map?**

I mean, theoretically you could draw maps in R and find a way to overlay gun sales over the maps, but I doubt there would be a great way of doing that unless you had the literal longitude and latitude of each gun sale. It would probably be better to have some theoretical justification for why you think this matters.

**3) There are a lot of gun laws. How should I select which laws to include in the regression?**

I think it just depends on your "big question". Remember that if you are being scientific about this, you should have some hypothesis about your intuition about these laws. Perhaps laws surrounding gun bans cause more/less gun sales after they are passed? Maybe buyback laws have a different effect? Given the vast range of laws out there, only you can decide that, which is why your big question matters.

**4) I currently have two similar explanatory variables: 1. total_laws (total number of laws a state has) and 2. percentage_of_laws_used (laws a state has/total possible laws*100). Should I exclude one of these variables from the regression?**

I would only pick one, but personally I would retain `total_laws` and if there is a need to use it as a proportion it can always be transformed later.

Comment: Thank you so much! To expand on Question 2, I want to see whether mass shootings in California have some correlation with loose gun laws in Texas. If it's difficult to obtain a weapon in California, could guns be going across borders from Texas into California, thereby minimizing the effect of gun laws on mass shootings?

Comment: If that is the specific hypothesis you want to test, you could create a categorical variable in your model for this purpose.